# How to find the nine tailsmans

Tags: dragons-crown

I've been on this part for about 3 hours trying to find the nine tailsmans and haven't even found one yet. I've done both A and B paths for most levels. Any advice on how to make any progress on this or some hint I might have missed?

Comment: All of the talismans come from beating the boss on the B side of the levels. Not sure how you are missing that....

Comment: Since I put up this question, I beat about 10 bosses on the B sides and actually did get one talisman from Medusa. I didn't get anything from any of the rest, so there must be something else to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got around to playing more on the B side bosses and ended up getting one from seemingly randomly from Medusa where I didn't fighting before. It looks like there's more to it than just beating the boss. I completed a few more B sides with nothing. I looked a little more into it and [found this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/633261-dragons-crown/66967931) with the full details for the special requirements for each boss to obtain a tailsman.

Ghost Ship Cove:

> Kraken collapses the cave and washes you away if you take too long. Watch the pillars in the background; they're your timer.

Bilbaron Fortress:

> Allies off-screen fire some big-ass cannon to destroy it if you take too long, no warning given.

Castle of the Dead:

> You have like 5 statues, after which you fail if the Wraith's not dead yet.

Temple Ruins:

> Medusa has no time limit if you fight her when she first spawns. If you run though, she runs away real quick the second time.

Underground Labyrinth

> No warning given for this one either; the door will just close immediately all on its own if you take too long.

Forgotten Sanctuary

> Warning given at about...two-thirds to three-quarters? Rannie goes "HEAVEN HELP US" in spite of his atheistic leanings. Take too long and the Archdemon gets impaled by many spears of light.

Old Capital

> Red Dragon has no time limit if you fight him in the treasure room. If you go out the door, you'll have an easier time but have a time limit of about...4 checkpoints (there's a box/ballista at each one, the dragon will stop there too)?

Mage's Tower

> There are only three floors in this fight; two wooden ones and a final one made of stone. You're given a warning about midway through every floor's...life span? Yeah. If the stone floor breaks the Chimera falls into lava and fries.

Lost Woods

> A message stating that there are voices echoing throughout the cave will appear at around the two-thirds mark. Take too long and...well, I'll leave it to you to find out. *winks*